# External monitor blurry

Tags: display

When I connect my Macbook Pro 13" 2015 to an external monitor, the quality is horrible. I know it' worse than it should be, as I compared it with my Windows.

This is a common problem, as I have seen hundreds of people asking forums going back years. But they all trace back to one solution: http://www.mathewinkson.com/2013/03/force-rgb-mode-in-mac-os-x-to-fix-the-picture-quality-of-an-external-monitor

But this does not work for me... The problems I have read are identical to mine. Is there any other way this could be fixed? I@m honestly considering returning my Mac at this point...

Comment: What brand is the external monitor? What resolution and refresh rate are you choosing? What connection method are you using on the MBP and the monitor (HDMI, Mini DisplayPort, VGA)?

Comment: Use a different interface like DVI or Display Port rather than HDMI and you shouldn't have this problem.

Comment: Have the same problem and I tried HDMI and VGA output. Both displayed very jagged fonts. Tried on three different monitors. When I go into the display settings it appears to be working in RGB, as intended.

Comment: My HDMI port is not working properly while my mini DP (thunderbolt 2) port is working perfectly with a same monitor. (On Macbook pro 2015 15-inch)

Answer (score 0):

Consider reducing your refresh rate; the blurriness is likely (although not necessarily!) chroma subsampling. (More information is available in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431895/how-can-i-get-macos-to-tell-me-what-chroma-sampling-or-subsampling-is-being-used), and if it's blurry for this same reason then this answer may be a duplicate.)